# Custom Policy does not respect email operating mode

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

When I run my signup_signin custom policy I receive "Sign in with your sign in name" in the UI, however I'd like for this to be an email address sign in. From what I can tell the TrustFrameworkBase has the operatingMode set to email, however I'm not certain why I'm not getting the correct outcome. Do I need to adjust the `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email` technical profile in some way?

TrustFrameworkBase unmodified from this:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml

TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="{Settings:Tenant}" PolicyId="B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" PublicPolicyUri="http://{Settings:Tenant}/B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>{Settings:Tenant}</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkBase</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <!-- Custom Attributes -->
      <!-- Seamless Migration -->
      <ClaimType Id="extension_RequiresMigration">
        <DisplayName>extension_RequiresMigration</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Migration status for the user's account. If true, reach out to legacy IdP to migrate user.</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="TokenSuccess">
        <DisplayName>TokenSuccess</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Add help text here</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>

      <ClaimType Id="MigrationRequired">
        <DisplayName>MigrationRequired</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Holds the value of false when the legacy IdP authentication succeeded</AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>

    </ClaimsSchema>

    <ContentDefinitions>

      <!-- This content definition is to render an error page that displays unhandled errors. -->
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.error">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/exception.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Error page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>

      <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/idpSelector.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
          <Item Key="language.intro">Sign in</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>

      <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections.signup">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/idpSelector.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
          <Item Key="language.intro">Sign up</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>

      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <LoadUri>https://{Settings:BlobStorageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/{Settings:BlobContainer}/html/sign_in.html</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>

      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>

      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.profileupdate">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>

      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account sign up page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>

      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account change password page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>

    </ContentDefinitions>
  </BuildingBlocks>

  <ClaimsProviders>
    <!-- Allows for referencing custom attributes in custom policies -->
    <!-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-custom-attributes#modify-your-custom-policy -->
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-Common">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ClientId">{Settings:B2CExtensionsAppId}</Item>
            <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId">{Settings:B2CExtensionsObjectId}</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <!-- Seamless Migration -->
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn - Read Migration Status</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Get-RequiresMigration-Status-SignIn">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_RequiresMigration" DefaultValue="false"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>REST API to communicate with Legacy IdP</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="UserMigrationViaLegacyIdP">
          <DisplayName>REST API call to communicate with Legacy IdP</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://{Settings:TIAPIBaseUrl}/SSOAuth</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="TokenSuccess" DefaultValue="false"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="MigrationRequired"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn - Write new password and unmark for migration</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-WritePasswordAndFlipMigratedFlag">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="MigrationRequired" PartnerClaimType="extension_RequiresMigration"/>
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common"/>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
    <!-- End Seamless Migration -->

    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="client_id">{Settings:ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId}</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">{Settings:IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId}</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="{Settings:ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId}" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="{Settings:IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId}" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <!-- Seamless Migration -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_RequiresMigration"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Get-RequiresMigration-Status-SignIn" ContinueOnError="false"/>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="UserMigrationViaLegacyIdP" ContinueOnError="false">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                  <Value>extension_RequiresMigration</Value>
                  <Value>False</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
            </ValidationTechnicalProfile>

            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-WritePasswordAndFlipMigratedFlag" ContinueOnError="false">
              <Preconditions>
                <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                  <Value>TokenSuccess</Value>
                  <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                </Precondition>
              </Preconditions>
            </ValidationTechnicalProfile>

            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive"/>
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <!-- End Seamless Migration-->
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>

  <!--UserJourneys>
    
    </UserJourneys-->

</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

SignUpOrSignin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="{Settings:Tenant}" PolicyId="B2C_1A_SignUp_Signin" PublicPolicyUri="http://{Settings:Tenant}/B2C_1A_SignUp_Signin" UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights" DeploymentMode="{Settings:ApplicationInsightsDeploymentMode}">

    <BasePolicy>
        <TenantId>{Settings:Tenant}</TenantId>
        <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
    </BasePolicy>

    <RelyingParty>
        <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
        <UserJourneyBehaviors>
            <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="{Settings:ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey}" DeveloperMode="{Settings:ApplicationInsightsDeveloperMode}" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
            <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
        </UserJourneyBehaviors>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
            <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration, DisableStrongPassword" />
            </InputClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />

            </OutputClaims>
            <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
    </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is just that it says “sign in with sign in name”? Functionally it’s still correct though - as in it only works if you enter an email?

Comment: @JasSuri I've attached an image as well. When I enter in an email address it says "please match the requested format". Entering just any text also displays the same message. The input type of the signin name is type="text".

Comment: @JasSuri Version 1.2.0 of the unifiedssp works exactly as I would expect it to. It correctly used email as the input type and the label/placeholder also says Email Address. I'm not sure what's going on with version 2.1.0 and the custom policies, perhaps something different has to be configured in the TrustFrameworkBase for that? It seems to be incorrect for version 2.1.0 if the expected behavior is to show Email Address when operatingMode = "Email".

Comment: Likely an issue with 2.1.0, don’t see much reason to use it for the combined sign up/in page over 1.2.0 though.

Comment: This hasn't been resolved yet with 2.1.2

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT This is still an issue, and if you want to use the new embedded password flow you have to use 2.1.2 and above. Tested with 2.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Page Layout Version 2.1.x as indicated by JasSuri. My current <strike>workaround</strike> working solution:

```xml
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement"
  StringId="local_intro_generic">Sign in with your email address</LocalizedString>

<LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" 
  ElementId="signInName" 
  StringId="DisplayName">Email Address</LocalizedString>
```

Its not perfect, but fine for the moment for me. The main problem is that the field is no longer of type email, which causes some issues (e.g. mobile keyboards, password managers)

edit: Adding the code by JasSuri in order to make this one "complete" answer:

> To fix email field type, use `<UserInputType>EmailBox</UserInputType>`.
>
> ```xml
>    <ClaimsSchema>
>      <ClaimType Id="signInName">
>        <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
>        <DataType>string</DataType>
>        <AdminHelpText>Email address that the user can use to sign in.</AdminHelpText>
>        <UserHelpText>Email address to use for signing in.</UserHelpText>
>        <UserInputType>EmailBox</UserInputType>
>      </ClaimType>
>    </ClaimsSchema>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

To fix email field type, use `<UserInputType>EmailBox</UserInputType>`.

```xml
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="signInName">
        <DisplayName>Email Address</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText>Email address that the user can use to sign in.</AdminHelpText>
        <UserHelpText>Email address to use for signing in.</UserHelpText>
        <UserInputType>EmailBox</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
```

We will try make this default in the starter pack.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#userinputtype

Comment: Fyi: There is another issue with embedded password reset: "forgot password?" link has a tabindex in between the signin name and the password, which breaks password managers.